# Strange UICollectionView behaviour

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I'm developing an app for the iPad where the user can add and delete items from a UICollectionView.

This is my entire ViewController code:

```
#import "ProjectsViewController.h"
#import "DetailViewController.h"
#import "MasterViewController.h"
#import "MyManager.h"

@interface ProjectsViewController ()
{
// Declare variables
NSArray *projects;
NSString *selectedProject;
NSMutableArray *_objects;
BOOL deleteAlert;
int editedProjects;
}
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UICollectionView *myCollectionView;

@end

@implementation ProjectsViewController
{
// Declare variables
NSString *deletedProject;
}
@synthesize prepareButton, aboutButton, createButton, editButton, editMode;

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
if (self) {
    // Custom initialization
}
return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view.
[_projectsCollectionView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"Cell" bundle:nil] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];

// Configure the style of the three big buttons
prepareButton.layer.cornerRadius = 7;
prepareButton.layer.borderWidth = 1;
prepareButton.layer.borderColor = [UIColor blueColor].CGColor;

aboutButton.layer.cornerRadius = 7;
aboutButton.layer.borderWidth = 1;
aboutButton.layer.borderColor = [UIColor blueColor].CGColor;

createButton.layer.cornerRadius = 7;
createButton.layer.borderWidth = 1;
createButton.layer.borderColor = [UIColor blueColor].CGColor;

editButton.layer.cornerRadius = 7;
editButton.layer.borderWidth = 1;
editButton.layer.borderColor = [UIColor blueColor].CGColor;
// (note - may prefer to use the tintcolor of the control)

// Set up projectsCollectionView
_projectsCollectionView.delegate = self;
_projectsCollectionView.dataSource = self;

#define saveNewProjects @"saveNewProjects"
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(resaveProjects:) name:saveNewProjects object:_projectCellClass];

#define deleteProject @"deleteProject"
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(deleteProjects:) name:deleteProject object:_projectCellClass];
}

- (void)resaveProjects:(NSNotification *)notification {
// Edit the edited projects and save all again
editedProjects = editedProjects - 1;

NSString *previousName;
NSString *newName;

// Create a MyManger instance
MyManager *sharedManager = [MyManager sharedManager];

// Set the new and old data from MyManager
previousName = sharedManager.oldProjectName;
newName = sharedManager.changedProjectName;

// Find that data in the _objects NSMutableArray
int projectIndex = [_objects indexOfObject:previousName];
[_objects removeObject:previousName];
[_objects insertObject:newName atIndex:projectIndex];

// Resave _objects
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:_objects forKey:@"myProjects"];

// Change the associated subjects to the new key
// Get the subjects
NSMutableArray *projectSubjects = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:previousName]];

// Remove the subjects for the previous key
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] removeObjectForKey:previousName];

// Save the subjects with the new key
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:projectSubjects forKey:newName];
}

- (void)deleteProjects:(NSNotification *)notification {
// Get the current project
NSString *currentProject = [[MyManager sharedManager] projectForDeletion];

[_objects removeObject:currentProject];

[_projectsCollectionView performBatchUpdates:^{

    NSArray *selectedItemsIndexPaths = [_projectsCollectionView indexPathsForSelectedItems];

    // Now delete the items from the collection view.
    [_projectsCollectionView deleteItemsAtIndexPaths:selectedItemsIndexPaths];

} completion:nil];

// Subtract 1 from editedProjects
editedProjects = editedProjects - 1;

// Set deletedProject
deletedProject = currentProject;

// Save the new objects
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:_objects forKey:@"myProjects"];

// Delete the associated subjects if any
[self deleteAssociatedSubjects];

// HERE
[_projectsCollectionView.collectionViewLayout invalidateLayout];
}

-(void)deleteAssociatedSubjects {
// Delete all the subjects inside this project
NSMutableArray *subjects = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:deletedProject]];

int subjectsCount = [subjects count];
for (int i = 0; i < subjectsCount; i++) {
    // Delete all the information associated with this subject

    // Create 3 save keys
    NSString *detailDescriptionKey = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", subjects[i], @"-detailDescription"];
    NSString *imageDescriptionKey = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", subjects[i], @"-imageDescription"];
    NSString *imageKey = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", subjects[i], @"-image"];
    NSString *notesKey = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", subjects[i], @"-notes"];

    // Delete the information from NSUserDefaults
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] removeObjectForKey:deletedProject];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] removeObjectForKey:detailDescriptionKey];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] removeObjectForKey:imageDescriptionKey];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] removeObjectForKey:imageKey];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] removeObjectForKey:notesKey];

    // Reload the UICollectionView
    _objects = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"myProjects"]];
    [_projectsCollectionView.collectionViewLayout invalidateLayout];
}
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{
[super viewDidAppear:animated];
}

-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
[super viewWillAppear:animated];
_objects = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"myProjects"]];
[_projectsCollectionView.collectionViewLayout invalidateLayout];

// Put the _objects in the singleton objects
MyManager *sharedManager = [MyManager sharedManager];
sharedManager.objects = _objects;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

#pragma mark - UICollectionView Datasource
// 1
- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)view numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
return _objects.count;
}
// 
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView: (UICollectionView *)collectionView {
return 1;
}
// 3
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)cv cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
ProjectCell *cell = (ProjectCell *)[cv dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
// Get the amount of subjects
        NSMutableArray *subjects = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:_objects[indexPath.row
]]];

// Count the subjects
int subjectsCount = [subjects count];

// Set the text and integer value
cell.projectLabel.text = _objects[indexPath.row];
cell.projectCount.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",subjectsCount];

// This helps on the animation
cell.layer.shouldRasterize = YES;

return cell;
}

- (IBAction)createButton:(id)sender {
if (editMode == YES) {
    // Create a new project
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Edit mode is on" message:@"Please exit edit mode before trying to create a project" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
    alert.alertViewStyle = UIAlertViewStyleDefault;
    [alert show];
} else {
    // Create a new project
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"New project" message:@"Enter a name for the project" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"Add", nil];
    alert.alertViewStyle = UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput;
    [alert show];
}
}

- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex{
if (deleteAlert == YES) {
    // Set deleteAlert to NO so that we don't mix this UIAlertView
    // with the create project UIAlertView
    deleteAlert = NO;
    // Delete the selected project
} else {
    // The user created a new project, add it
    if (buttonIndex == 1) {
        // Get the input text
        NSString *newProject = [[alertView textFieldAtIndex:0] text];

        // Initialize objects
        if (!_objects) {
            _objects = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        }

        // Add the new project
        if (newProject.length == 0) {
            // No input, tell the user
            UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle: @"Enter a name" message: @"Please enter a name first" delegate: nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil]; [alert show];
        } else {
            // Check if the entered subject already exists
            if ([_objects containsObject:newProject]) {
                // The subject already exist, tell the user
                UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle: @"Already exists" message: @"This project already exist, sorry" delegate: nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil]; [alert show];
            } else {
                // Ready to add the project, go ahead
                [_objects insertObject:newProject atIndex:0];
                NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0];
                [_projectsCollectionView insertItemsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath]];

                [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:_objects forKey:@"myProjects"];
            }
        }
    } else {

    }
}
}

- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:     (NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
// Get the tapped cell
ProjectCell *projectCell = (ProjectCell *)[collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];

if (editMode == YES) {
    if (editedProjects == 0) {
        // Set deleteAlert to YES so that we don't mix this UIAlertView
        // with the create project UIAlertView
        deleteAlert = YES;

        // Set editMode to YES for the selected cell
        [projectCell editProject];

        // Prepare the project cell
        projectCell.projectTextField.text = projectCell.projectLabel.text;

        // Set the firstProjectsViewController to YES
        // indicating that the next tapped cell will be second in line
        // in case the user decides to edit a new cell without closing this

        if (projectCell.editMode == YES) {
            // Do nothing
        } else if (projectCell.editMode == NO) {
            // Resave projects
            [self resaveProjects:nil];
        }

        // Increase editedProjects with 1
        editedProjects++;
    } else if (editedProjects == 1) {
        // Check if the tapped cell is being edited
        if (projectCell.editMode == YES) {
            // Set deleteAlert to YES so that we don't mix this UIAlertView
            // with the create project UIAlertView
            deleteAlert = YES;

            // Set editMode to YES for the selected cell
            [projectCell editProject];

            // Prepare the project cell
            projectCell.projectTextField.text = projectCell.projectLabel.text;

            // Set the firstProjectsViewController to YES
            // indicating that the next tapped cell will be second in line
            // in case the user decides to edit a new cell without closing this

            if (projectCell.editMode == YES) {
                // Do nothing
            } else if (projectCell.editMode == NO) {
                // Resave projects
                [self resaveProjects:nil];
            }

            // It decreases editedProjects with 1, code is "unlocated"
        } else if (projectCell.editMode == NO) {
            // Tell the user that only 1 project is editable at a time
            UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Can only edit 1" message:@"You can only edit 1 project at a time" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
            alert.alertViewStyle = UIAlertViewStyleDefault;
            [alert show];
        }
    }
} else {
    // Set the open project
    MyManager *sharedManager = [MyManager sharedManager];
    sharedManager.openProject = nil;
    sharedManager.openProject = @"";
    sharedManager.openProject = _objects[indexPath.item];

    // Open the selected project and dismiss this ViewController
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
}

- (void)selectedProject {
// The user opened a project - CODE NOT USED ATM
UIStoryboard *mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil]; // assuming your split view controller in storyboard with name "Main" in project's main bundle
UISplitViewController *splitViewController = (UISplitViewController *)[mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"splitVC"];

UINavigationController *navigationController = [splitViewController.viewControllers lastObject];
splitViewController.delegate = (id)navigationController.topViewController;

// Close the ProjectsViewController and open the selected project
[UIView transitionFromView:[[[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window] rootViewController] view]
                    toView:splitViewController.view
                  duration:0.5
                   options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromLeft
                completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                    [[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window] setRootViewController:splitViewController];
                }];
}
- (IBAction)editAction:(id)sender {
// Enter editMode leave editMode
if (editMode == YES) {
    if (editedProjects == 0) {
        // Disable editMode
        editMode = NO;
        [editButton setTitle:@" Edit " forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    } else {
        // The user is currently still editing a project, tell him/her
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle: @"Edit mode is on" message: @"It looks like you're still editing a project, please finish editing it by tapping on it before trying to exit edit mode" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
    }
} else {
    // Enable editMode
    editMode = YES;
    [editButton setTitle:@" Finish " forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
}

/*
#pragma mark - Navigation

// In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
// Get the new view controller using [segue destinationViewController].
// Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
}
*/

@end
```

This is the behaviour:

- Delete item (successful)
- Tries to add new item, unsuccessful (only adds in NSUserDefaults, nothing on-screen)
- Next attempt shows a weird cell with all ui elements visible (normally 2-3 controls would be hidden)
- Next attempt is completely successful

Does anyone have any idea on why this happens and how I can fix it?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I see `-(IBAction)deleteProjectAction` but no method to save/add a new one. What method are you calling where you'd expect that to work? The only place you save to NSUserDefaults is in the "deleteProject" method, which seems a little weird - maybe refactor that to a separate update method if you actually do that in multiple places? 

As for the controls, I'd say the "editMode" is set the wrong way during the unsuccessful add attempt so the elements appear. But without the code for the addProject method it's hard to track.

Comment: Sorry, see my updated question with add code @mc01

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the last else block successfully adds the newProject to NSUserDefaults, but `insertItemsAtIndexPaths` doesn't actually do anything?

Per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13392413/uicollectionview-insertitemsatindexpaths-throws-exception?rq=1) using `reloadData` doesn't seem to work well w/UICollectionView. Maybe that call you have in viewWillAppear is conflicting w/the other attempts to update `_projectsCollectionView` ... Could change it to `reloadSections` or `invalidateLayout` instead to see if that solves the first problem.

As for the subviews showing, how do you initialize the cells? It's likely somewhere you leave editingMode set to "YES" when it should be a "NO." If that's a property on the cell itself when it gets dequeued & reused it could leave those views visible for another item. Your code above only shows IBAction for ending editing, not for starting/toggling it, so it's hard to tell where this error might originate.

You also have this code:

```
-(void)editProject {
if (editMode == YES) {
// disable editMode and update the project cell
editMode = NO;
_projectTextField.hidden = YES;
_editModeLabel.hidden = YES;
_deleteButton.hidden = YES;

// Call editingfinished to save
[self editingFinished:nil]; ...
```

Which does the same thing as just calling `[self editingFinished:nil];` 
because it contains the exact same lines. If you have a similar if/else check in another method to start editing, that may be where the subview visibility is going screwy.

Comment: I uploaded my entire ViewController code if you wanted to take a look

Comment: Tried the invalidaLayout and reloadSections - none worked. See my viewDidLoad for how the cell is dequed @mc01

Comment: Without messing w/the whole project file, not really ;) If the "reloadSections" method didn't work I dunno. Could be any number of things ... 

The block-based "performBatchUpdates" seems to work for deleting, so maybe try that when adding/editing just to see if it works.

When adding a project you have about 5 nested if-else checks - maybe one of them isn't getting hit or acting as expected?

Comment: You also have "editMode" both as a viewController property (in the .h I presume) and as a property of the custom cells. The code you posted before I think just used the VC's "editMode" to toggle visibility of sub-views though, right? Or is it the cell's "editMode" that controls what's shown?

Unrelated to your question, but at one point you set `sharedManager.openProject` to `nil, @""` and `indexPath.item` one after the other. You should only need the last one, but this also assumes that indexPath.item actually exists. Maybe it doesn't?  
That's all I got - good luck!

Comment: Can you believe it? I put up NSLog's on all the possibilities on the nested if-else statements and it turned out to be YES when it should be NO and then changing it to NO when that happenend - making it work the second time. So atleast that's fixed, now I just need to sort out the weird visibillity issues. Each and every cell has it's own editMode that toggles the visibility of the subviews according to a user's tap. @mc01

Comment: After hours and HOURS of trying to fix this - it turned out to be what I mentioned in my last comment + this simple line of code: [self editProject];

Thanks a lot for your help! ;)

Comment: Nice :) Glad you got it fixed! Sorry I wasn't able to be more specific, but hey it works!

Comment: No problem ;) - your help was the last piece in the puzzle ;) - aaalmost ready for app store submission :D